# If I smoke before Ramadan, but not during Ramadan, does it affect my fasts?

Tags: ramadan, sawm

If I smoke before Ramadan, but not during Ramadan, does it affect my fasts? Analogous to how drinking alcohol means your fasts or salaahs will not be accepted for forty days.

Comment: Asak...going on a tangent plz also research on why smoking is considered makruh if not totally Haraam by a majority of the Ulema today. May Allah guide us all.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, it won't affect your fasts as long as you're NOT smoking while you're fasting.

PS:
Many brothers and sisters consider Ramadan as a perfect opportunity for quitting. Please at least give a try.

Comment: _as long as you are smoking while fasting_ --- probably, you wanted to say "not smoking"

Comment: yes, you are right. my bad. :) fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would just have to stop smoking a couple months before ramadan like how it says your fasts wont be accepted if you have alcohol in your system

Comment: Please share a reference to corroborate your view.